# How to change x axis and y axis label in DBChart Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, bar-chart, delphi-7

I want the x-axis to be the month while the y-axis to be the amount of letter that I made (the green one) and the amount of letter that I received (the red One)
[image: This is the chart that I made]

edit:
I want the chart to look like this
[image: the chart]
the vertical line is the amount, the horizontal line is the month, the red bar is how much letter that I received, the green bar is how much letter that I made.
This is the setting for dataset
[image]

Comment: It is unclear whether your problem is to get the data from a db (as you are using `TDBChart`) or declaring the data series or formatting the bars, or what? Please edit your question to clarify and show details of what you have done so far.

Comment: So you want horizontal bars instead of vertical ones (like in the image?)

Answer (score 0):

in Source code
set max value to your maximum chart value